# Having trouble 'throwing' rigid bodies with velocity

Tags: physics, rigid-body-simulation

I'm trying to throw a sphere with a horizontal velocity in a similar way as in this video https://youtu.be/TFseMPGRz1Q.

I have the initial location keyframed on frame 1 and the new location keyframed on frame 2. Also on frame 2 I keyframed the animated checkerbox On, and on frame 3 I keyframed it off, as detailed in the video.

However when I run the sim, at frame 3 the velocity does not carry forward and instead the sphere drops straight down by gravity. Why is it doing this?

Incorrect result:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/TusWc.jpg

Comment: Maybe your gravity is too strong? (Scene context > Gravity)

Comment: Try to give the animation a few more frames to settle the velocity. I don't know why it's needed though.

Comment: To add to @Jackdraw's comment, as well as several more frames, make sure the exit frame isn't curved, such as Bezier.  You have to leave the animated part abruptly to 'pass on' all the inertia.  You could just use 'Linear' for the interpolation. (select all the keyframes in the Dopesheet and press T --> Linear.